# Bundled a library from Bower using Gulp and it's not recognized in final result

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I'm new to using Gulp and basically engaged in an exercise to understand all these details.

I've installed a package through Bower called Skrollr - https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Gulp Task

```
gulp.task('browserify', () => {
    // For the sake of brevity, I'm only listing one package here
    var bower = [
        'bower_components/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js',
    ];

    return browserify(bower)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

app.js

```
skrollr.init({
    smoothScrolling: false,
    mobileDeceleration: 0.004
});
```

Index.html

```
<script src="dist/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/app.js"></script>
```

And the skrollr library seems to be bundled successfully within vendor.js because the code is there and so is the license agreement for the library.

However when the page is loaded, I get this error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Skrollr is not defined

When I load the CDN of the skrollr library, everything works fine - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/skrollr

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/app.js"></script>
```

So something is possibly going wrong when I bundle it?

**Additionally**:

In case you ask why I am using Bower (someone elsewhere asked)? I'm new to this. I presumed it was a legit tool to use for package management.

Answer (score 0):

You need two `browserify` tasks:

- A `browserify-vendor` task that bundles your vendor files and exposes them so that they can be `required()` from your **app.js**.
- A `browserify-app` task that bundles your app files with external dependencies to your vendor files.

Here's what that would look like:

```
gulp.task('browserify-vendor', () => {
  var skrollr = './bower_components/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js';
  return browserify(skrollr)
    .require(skrollr, {expose:'skrollr'})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('browserify-app', () => {
  return browserify('src/js/app.js')
    .external('skrollr')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['browserify-vendor', 'browserify-app']);
```

Finally you need to `require()` the browserified `skrollr` module from your **app.js**:

```
var skrollr = require('skrollr');

skrollr.init({
  smoothScrolling: false,
  mobileDeceleration: 0.004
});
```

You might want to check out the [Using browserify to bundle separate app and vendor files](https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes/tree/master/browserify-separating-app-and-vendor-bundles) recipe.